# What does input_shape mismatch means

Tags: tensorflow2.0

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [6,2,3] vs. [6,1] what does        
 this means.
```

what does incompatible shape means

InvalidArgumentErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<  ipython-input-28-c2078c9c10e8> in ()
----> 1 odel.fit(x, y, epochs=500)

```
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
 packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.pyc in __exit__(self, 
 type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
 526             None, None,
 527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
 -->  528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
 529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it 
stays alive
 530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback 
  due to

 InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [6,2,3] vs. [6,1]
  [ ]

 > Blockquote


   import tensorflow as tf
   import numpy as np
   from tensorflow import keras

  odel = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=3)])

   odel.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

   x = np.array([[[1,2],[6,3]],[[3,4],[6,3]],[[4,5],[6,6]],[[5,6],[6,6]], 
                [[6,7],[6,4]],[[7,8],[6,2]]], dtype=float)
   y = np.array([6, 10, 15, 17, 17,17], dtype=float)

   odel.fit(x, y, epochs=500)

   a=np.array([[2,3]])`enter code here`
     print(odel.predict(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things that needs to be addressed in the code

1- InputShape

The first layer of tf.Sequential should have an InputShape. It is the shape of one element of the features

2 - the label

The label is at least of two dimensions (likewise for the features). y is of shape `[6]`, whereas it should be of shape `[b, 3]`, 3 being the value of unit of the last layer and b is the number of batches. Looking at the features, b is 6